# Write script to Migrate data from one database to another in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I want to migrate data from one database to another. I have written my sql statements to do so. However, the issue I a, facing is, I need to "use databasename GO" before executing the query (Can I fire use B and A at the same time to run my script?). Below is my query.

```
Use B GO
Use A GO

IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 FROM B.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_schema = 'dbo' and table_name = 'Animal')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Table does not exist'
        RETURN
    END
GO

IF NOT EXISTS (select 1 FROM B.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where table_schema = 'dbo' and table_name = 'Animal')
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Table does not exist'
        RETURN
    END 
 GO


SET IDENTITY_INSERT B.[dbo].Animal ON GO

INSERT INTO B.[dbo].Animal
(Id, Name)
SELECT (Id, Name)
From A.dbo.Animal

GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT B.[dbo].Animal OFF 
GO
```

Would this work to move the data?

Comment: I'm curious why you do the existence check twice on B, typo maybe?  You wouldn't need to check for it on A, I'm assuming A is the source, because if it doesn't exist it doesn't matter if your script has error, you can't copy nothing.  Do you have access to ssms?  Use the Tasks and have it generate the script for both the schema and data.  Choose "script if not exists" as true and then you can also bring over your constraints and indexes.

Comment: If the databases are on the same server you can use [dbname].[dbo].[tablename]. You don't need to use your USE statements.

Comment: Yup. My bad. I copy/pasted it twice. A is there since a while now, so I am not checking for it. B is the new database going forward. The tables for B are already created along with the constraints, however as it is a new Database so I am validating it (safeguard), I can live without checking if B exist or not. I will try SSMS (do not have access to it).